# Spacing math with theme.spacing() in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUI v4, I had bits like this in my JSS classes:

```
paddingTop: theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight + theme.spacing(1)
```

In v5 however, `theme.spacing()` returns a string instead of a number. So the above statement would set paddingTop to `568px`, which is `56+'8px'` So what is now the proper way to do math with spacing?

Comment: **See Also**: This issue [Allow theme.spacing() to return a number](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29086)

Answer (score 6):

MUI `Theme` is just an [object](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/#main-content), you can extend its functionalities from the base theme pretty easily. Once you define and inject your custom theme through `ThemeProvider` component, you can start using it anywhere in the children.

The method below create an enhanced version of the original theme with a new method `gap(spacing)` that returns the space value in number without the `px` unit at the end. You can also use `theme.space[index]` to access the value as another alternative:

```
const createExtendedTheme = () => {
  const defaultTheme = createTheme();
  const gap = (spacing: number) => parseInt(defaultTheme.spacing(spacing), 10);

  return createTheme({
    gap,
    space: {
      0: gap(0),
      1: gap(1),
      2: gap(2),
      3: gap(3),
      4: gap(4),
      5: gap(5),
    },
  });
};
```

```
// For Typescript users
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface ExtendedTheme {
    gap: (spacing: number) => number;
    space: {
      0: number;
      1: number;
      2: number;
      3: number;
      4: number;
      5: number;
    };
  }
  interface Theme extends ExtendedTheme {}
  interface ThemeOptions extends ExtendedTheme {}
}
```

### Usage

```
const theme = createExtendedTheme();

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Content />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

```
function Content() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: theme.gap(5) * 2,
        height: theme.gap(1) + theme.gap(2),
        height: theme.space[1] + theme.space[2], // same as above
        bgcolor: "tomato"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I would use parseFloat instead of parseInt since spacing can now return floats. Also, should probably use calc since spacing isn't guaranteed to use px units.

Answer (score 1):

```
`calc(${theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight} + ${theme.spacing(1)})`
```

Comment: This does not work.
It will render `calc(24 + 32px)` (values are examples). `calc` does not support that.

Comment: This does work when you add a unit after the `minHeight`, e.g.:
`calc(${theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight}px + ${theme.spacing(1)})`

Answer (score 0):

You can override the theme to provide another function that returns the spacing as a number:

```
// If you are using Typescript
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface ExtendedTheme {
    spacingNumber(spacing: number): number;
  }
  interface Theme extends ExtendedTheme {}
}

const createExtendedTheme = () => {
  const defaultTheme = createTheme();
  const spacingNumber = (spacing) => Number(theme.spacing(spacing).slice(0, -2));

  return createTheme({
    spacingNumber
  });
};
```

Usage

```
const theme = createExtendedTheme();

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Content />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

See: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29086